# Element not found when finding table selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to read the table and get the values for the columns of address and value. The can't find  element error is returned.
The page: https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jXZk.png)

My code:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()

ga=pandas.read_csv("contracts/adresses.csv")
for i in range (ga.size-1):
        fj=ga.iloc[i][0]
        # driver.get("https://etherscan.io/address/"+str(fj))

driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

frame = wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tokeholdersiframe")))
print("udj")


    
simpleTable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/table")
    
    
rows = simpleTable.find_elementsBy.TAG_NAME("tr")

    
for i in range(1,len(rows)):
        cols = i.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME("td"))
        for g in cols:
            g.getText()
```

HTML code:

```
<thead class="thead-light">
<tr>
<th scope="col" width="1">Rank</th>
<th scope="col">Address</th>
<th scope="col">Quantity
</th>
<th scope="col">Percentage</th>
<th id="col_value_Title" scope="col">Value</th>
<th id="col_analytics_Title" scope="col">Analytics</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Public Tag: Binance 7
(0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8)"><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8" target="_parent">Binance 7</a></span></td><td>8,623,839.536582375549486936</td><td>52.0150% <div class="progress mt-1" style="height:2px;"><div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width:100.0000%;" aria-valuenow="52.0150" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div></div></td><td>$3,659,513,869.72</td><td><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0xbe0eb53f46cd790cd13851d5eff43d12404d33e8#tokenAnalytics" target="_parent"><i class="ml-2 fas fa-chart-line fa-lg"></i></a></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Public Tag: Binance 8
(0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec)"><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec" target="_parent">Binance 8</a></span></td><td>4,500,000</td><td>27.1419% <div class="progress mt-1" style="height:2px;"><div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width:52.1809%;" aria-valuenow="27.1419" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div></div></td><td>$1,909,568,509.93</td><td><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec#tokenAnalytics" target="_parent"><i class="ml-2 fas fa-chart-line fa-lg"></i></a></td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Public Tag: Binance 9
(0x001866ae5b3de6caa5a51543fd9fb64f524f5478)"><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0x001866ae5b3de6caa5a51543fd9fb64f524f5478" target="_parent">Binance 9</a></span></td><td>588,959.49910460999996837</td><td>3.5523% <div class="progress mt-1" style="height:2px;"><div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width:6.8294%;" aria-valuenow="3.5523" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div></div></td><td>$249,924,114.03</td><td><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0x001866ae5b3de6caa5a51543fd9fb64f524f5478#tokenAnalytics" target="_parent"><i class="ml-2 fas fa-chart-line fa-lg"></i></a></td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td><span><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0xb4b3351918a9bedc7d386c6a685c42e69920b34d" target="_parent">0xb4b3351918a9bedc7d386c6a685c42e69920b34d</a></span></td><td>211,336.9</td><td>1.2747% <div class="progress mt-1" style="height:2px;"><div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width:2.4506%;" aria-valuenow="1.2747" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div></div></td><td>$89,680,508.72</td><td><a href="/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0xb4b3351918a9bedc7d386c6a685c42e69920b34d#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of syntax error in the code:

```
rows = simpleTable.find_elementsBy.TAG_NAME("tr")
```

should be

```
rows = simpleTable.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"tr")
```

And this

```
cols = i.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME("td"))
```

should be

```
cols = rows[i].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"td")
```

And to get `Text` from a WebElement in python use `.text` or `.get_attribute("innerText")`
It should be something like this:

```
print(g.text)
```

Try with this code:

```
simpleTable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='maintable']//table")

rows = simpleTable.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"tr")

for i in range(1,len(rows)):
        cols = rows[i].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"td")
        for g in cols:
            print(g.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`!pip install selenium (jupyter notebook)`

or

```
pip install selenium ( command prompt)
```

Install and try it again !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).